# "So though" vs "so even though"

Tags: phrases, expressions, sentence

Do they mean the same? Or they mean slightly different things?

Example:

> They both had passion for music, so, (even) though their tastes differed,
>   they never ran out of topic to talk about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Though** (the informal form of *although*) expresses the idea of contrast. In this case, it expresses the contrast between ***their tastes differed*** and ***they never ran out of topic to talk about.***

Meanwhile, **even though** is stronger, more emphatic than *just* ***though***. You see, when the word **even** stands alone, it functions as an adverb and means **this is more than or less than expected**. Again, you are registering something that may be surprising when you state it.

In your example, that will mean that, quite *surprisingly*, **despite the fact** that *their tastes differed*, they both never ran out of topic to talk about. And it is **surprising** that they never did, you *might **previously** think* that they ran out of topic because of the their different tastes.

If you only use *though*, it's not that surprising, nor it is less/more than you expected from the case. It's just showing a contrast.

The word **so** there could possibly state there is **a cause** why they never ran out of topic, which is that *they both had passion for music*.

As for me, I choose not to use **even** here. Because the reason why they never ran out topic is there. It's explained in the first part of the sentence (*they both had passion*). So it's not surprising.

**Conclusion**: The most possible logical choices of sentence that I can come up with are:

> *They both had passion for music. So, (al)though their tastes differed, they never ran out of topic to talk about.*

Or:

> *Even though their tastes of music differed, they never ran out of topic to talk about.*